# What does the Peacekeeper shout when landing combos/special attacks?

Tags: for-honor

Sometimes when successfully landing special attacks, such as the Riposting Stab, the Peacekeeper can be heard shouting something along the lines of "pierri!"

It can be heard in this [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/6avrKzRxCO4) at 1:13.

What is the actual word she is saying, and what does it mean when translated into English?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What she is saying here is

> Peri!

Which means "Die!" or "Be destroyed!".

All the battle shouts of the heroes in the Knights faction are Latin.

Source: [For Honor Wiki](http://forhonor.wikia.com/wiki/Peacekeeper#Quotes)

Comment: Perish might be the best translation.